# Combine Angular and Blade expressions

Tags: javascript, angularjs, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel and Angular together and I was wondering if it's possible and how can I combine both Laravel and Angular expressions?

For example if I have a route that has a parameter that I need from a angular variable:

```
data-ng-click="myFunction({{ URL::route("myRoute", [<% myObj.id %>]); }})"
```

Where `<% %>` are my changed angular open/close expression tags and `{{}}` blades open/close expression tags.

Comment: well since you already changed the interpolation provider, I would guess that your angular expression probably needs to be provided to Laravel as a string, i.e. `'<% myObj.id %>'`

Comment: @Claies Just tried, the angular value isn't injected and the output is '<% myObj.id %>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It won't work.

Blade code(php) is run server-side and angular(js) is run on client side. Meaning blade code is **always** executed *before* angular code while your code **requires** blade to execute *after* angular.

If you were to change your expression so blade is required to run before angular, then it could work.

But, you will soon end up with lots of spaghetti code that way. Blade and angular are very different technologies. Do not intermix them unless it is  extremely necessary. And even then make sure to comment your reasons .

Comment: I was only injecting blade for the routes and I don't see any other way around this using pure angular other than hard coding the URL's in angular. I got around this by injecting the blade routes and then replacing the parameters in the url pattern with values in angular. Is this an okay approach or can you suggest anything different?

Comment: so, you require angular code to get urls dynamically(as myObj.id is dynamic) from server? I would use ajax in such cases.

Comment: I'm using blade to inject the laravel routes (URL's) from the server, I needed these routes/URL's in angular to make further ajax requests etc.

Comment: As I said, I could just hard code the url's in angular for my requests but then I would be maintaining the URL's in two or more places..

Comment: bootstrap urls via ajax, you require two type of urls
1) static urls for fetching dynamic data  via ajax. Can be generateed via blade alone
2) dynamic urls for more ajax. Use type 1 urls for fetching them through ajax and then use them for further ajax

Comment: it may seems a little tricky, but it is simple.  try it a little yourself. if some problem occurs, then ask at SO :)

Comment: That is the scenario. My problem that I stressed was that the type 1 URL's had some parameters where the values were from some angular objects and that was my reason for trying to inject angular into the blade. Of course if there are no parameters in the blade route then there's no issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99915/discussion-between-raj-kamal-and-joe).